# Is there a workaround for shadowdom and Google/Leaflet Maps and Dart in mobile creating exception, thus preventing click events from being processed?

Tags: google-maps, mobile, dart, leaflet, polymer

I'm coming across this bug , while running my Polymer Element inside a mobile browser.  Chrome in this case.

```
DOMException {message: "Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': The event provided is null.", name: "InvalidStateError", code: 11, stack: "Error: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'Event…/packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.debug.js:2678:12)",
INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1…}
"Error: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': The event provided is null.
at o.Map.Tap.o.Handler.extend._simulateEvent (http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js:9:5230)
at o.Map.Tap.o.Handler.extend._onUp (http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js:9:4807)
at Document.t.(anonymous function).s (http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js:8:20285)
at invoke (http://localhost:8080/packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.debug.js:2805:28)
at dispatchBubbling (http://localhost:8080/packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.debug.js:2753:12)
at dispatchEvent (http://localhost:8080/packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.debug.js:2706:9)
at HTMLDocument.dispatchOriginalEvent (http://localhost:8080/packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.debug.js:2678:12)" shadow_dom.debug.js:2816
```

It only occurs in a mobile browser, when using Google Maps or Leaflet maps which involves using the

```
import 'dart:js';
```

library.  There is a bug report which seems to be same issue here https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16125, but no answer of how to deal with it.

To see if the same issue affected Leaflet I also implemented it using the

```
'dart:js'
```

library, but get the same issue.

Is there a solution/work around for this?

Comment: This is a bug in polymer/dart and/or their combination with these libraries, not in Google Maps or Leaflet themselves, which work great on their own. I'd recommend updating the title to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you, maybe I will, however I have only come across this in Google maps and leaflet maps, nothing else so far. Also you're the only one who pointed out this fact so far. The question still stands regardless if Google maps and leaflet maps work fine on their own.

Comment: Maybe a problem with the polyfills. Have you tried one of the dev releases like 0.10.0-pre.1?

Comment: Yes, same problem.  I assume you're talking about the latest Polymer Dart dev version?  If so, then I have, but not since I asked this question.  Same problem, just from a different polyfill source code, not shadowdom.debug.js, can't remember the filename.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I think you might be onto something there, though why it's only a problem in mobile browsers is beyond me, and it's only events generated from a JavaScript source.

Comment: If it's the polyfills then I think Polymer.js would have the same problem. Can you try that (jsfiddle or something)? You already added the `polymer` tag but there was no response from them either.

Comment: I think this is the same problem https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16125

Comment: What I suspect it is is something to do with events from JS being emitted, and still being delayed by the mobile browser delayed click problem.  Somehow this is being bubbled up still with the event being null, as it hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Yeah the bug you refer to is in the question above, thanks though